# Unable to find an entry point named 'GetCurrentPackageId' in DLL 'kernel32.dll' when using Visual Studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.NET which calls an asmx web service. It works fine on one machine with or without using the debugger in VS 2010. On another machine, it gives an error "Unable to find an entry point named 'GetCurrentPackageId' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'" in the web service constructor and when launched in the debugger. If the app is running without the debugger it runs fine. If the debugger is attached to w3wp.exe, the app runs fine and breakpoints are reached. This is in Windows 7 64bit. The same app exhibits the same behavior under VS11beta.

Any ideas why I get this error when using the debugger.

Comment: Searching for 'GetCurrentPackageId' found only references to Windows8 preview kernel. So something is very strange in the setup of your PC.

Comment: I have never installed Windows8.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich I have the same problem, did you solve it? It occurs when I use `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StepList));`.

Answer (score 2):

I recently noticed the same thing started on a machine that previously worked just fine.  The only change that occurred was the installation of Visual Studio 2011 Ultimate Beta 1.  The problem has unfortunately persisted after the uninstall of 2011.

More specifically, it's happening with projects that were opened with the beta.

Comment: This was happening to me even for executables not built by my machine, so I guess in my case it's nothing to do with the actual build, but with the runtime environment.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this problem and deleted my [projectname].suo file. This file exists in the directory where the .sln file is located.

Once I did this the problem no longer exists.

Be sure to back up this file before you try this, and know that you may have to reset a few things (startup project, etc)

Comment: I also installed VS2011, but not Ultimate. I uninstalled it fairly quickly. I did not notice the problem with this project until several weeks later when I revisited it to add a feature.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown and handled deep inside the .NET Framework. However, you have enabled the option to break even on properly handled exceptions. (I know, because I did too.) You can safely disable that for `EntryPointNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Microsoft is working on this issue

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/732334/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-getcurrentpackageid-in-dll-kernel32-dll

Comment: the link is broken link